# Javascript store <select> dropdown values within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, while-loop, sum

I'm wondering if it's possible to store the selected values from a `<select>`in a JS array.

What I finally need to do is calculate the highest 6 values out of around 10 dropdowns, which I think I can do by using the JS Math.max() function.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some sample code:

```
<? while($subjects = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<select class="points">
<optgroup label="<?=$subjects['name']?>">
  <option value="100">A1</option>
  <option value="90">A2</option>
  <option value="85">B1</option>
  <option value="80">B2</option>
  <option value="75">B3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<? } ?>

<script>....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this (JQuery):

```
var selected = new Array();
            $('.points option:selected').each(function() {
                selected.push($(this).val());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selects = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('select'));
selects.forEach(function (elem, i){
    var value = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    //Do something with this value. Push it to an array, perhaps.
});​
```

This assumes that all the `select`s on the page should be included. If that isn't the case, then you should use `document.getElementsByClassName` or a similar, more appropriate selector instead.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xHrY/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var selectValues = [];
var selectNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("points");
for (var i = 0; i < selectNodeList.length; i++) {
    selectValues.push(selectNodeList[i].value)
}
// selectValues array now stores values of all <select> lists with class "points"
```